# Reflection from a potential step: an interesting question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am studying the reflection from a potential step. I have one interesting question.

When Kinetic energy $E$ > $U$ (potential energy), is it possible that we would have a probability wave for electrons, in the region past the potential step, with same kinetic energy $K$ (no energy change like quantum tunneling)?

Comment: Yes of course. What makes you think that would not be the case? If it can happen with E<U why would it not happen with E>U? The former is harder to grasp than the latter, surely.

Comment: I was 70% sure, but wanted to get expert advice.

Comment: Anyway, then it will be a dull probability graph- straight line.
Not like the exponential one in tunneling.